# Search for two or more words inside a row in google spreadsheet

Tags: regex, search, google-sheets

I want to search two words inside a cell lets say my cell contains the following text **"hi this is a cell"** and I want to get the cells containing the words "hi" and "cell". I tried using regex but it throws an error, apparently Google spreadsheet regex search don't support question marks cause this expression (?=hi)(?=cell) throws:  Oops. A server error occurred.

Any ideas my friends??

Thanks in advance and have a great day!!

Comment: Google content manager seems to have very limited regex support, not only in terms of lookarounds, but also in terms of quantifiers.  Perhaps there is a Find method equivalent you could use to search each cell for the two words separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
\bhi\b.*\bcell\b
```